# sqlite's fetchall returns None instead of an empty list

Tags: python, database, sqlite

According to the [sqlite3 docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall), `fetchall()` returns a list (empty if no rows meet the search criteria).  On occasion, not repeatable, I am getting a return value `None`.  What could `None` indicate, failed access to the DB?  a missing table?

Comment: From a brief look at the source, it does not seem possible, barring memory corruption, for sqlite3's cursor's `fetchall` to return `None`. Are you sure that's actually what happened, and that you're not, for example, swallowing an exception and returning `None` yourself somewhere?

Comment: @Thomas  Thank you.  This has pointed me in the right direction.  If you would like, you could place the first sentence of your comment as an answer and I will mark this question closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a brief look at the source, it does not seem possible, barring memory corruption, for sqlite3's cursor's `fetchall` to return `None`. You must be doing something else that results in `None`.

Answer (score 0):

when `fetchall()` returns `[]` `fetchone()` returns `None`
are you sure you weren't accidently using `fetchone()` ?